# How do I write a rails 6 `form_with` block to make a JSON call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-with

Here's the code:

```
<%= form_with(url: invitations_path, remote: true, 'data-type' => 'json') do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :from, user_id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :to, secret_crush_id %>
<%= f.submit "Send a valentine?", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the generated HTML:

```
 <form action="/invitations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="[OMITTED]" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="hidden" name="from" id="from" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="hidden" name="to" id="to" value="2" autocomplete="off" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send a valentine?" class="btn btn-secondary" data-disable-with="Send a valentine?" />
</form>
```

Nothing in the generated HTML suggests (to me at least) that this should be an ajax call, and in fact the controller reports it has format `.html`.

Also, this form is coming from a page based on a different rails model, in case that's a factor.

What do I need to do to make this an ajax call?

Comment: Look at the `:local` option in the [`form_with` docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)